# Underlying hyperlink href address from css selector

Tags: r, css-selectors, rvest

This bit of code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4116284/"

director <- read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes(".summary_text+ .credit_summary_item .itemprop") %>% 
    html_text()
```

Will grab the plain text value "Chris McKay" (the director of the new LEGO Batman Movie). The underlying hyperlink href address, however, points to:
`http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0003021?ref_=tt_ov_dr`

I want that. How can I adjust my css selector to grab the underlying hyperlink href address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `href` attr of the parent `a` tag:

```
director <- read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes(".summary_text+ .credit_summary_item span a") %>% 
    html_attr('href')
```